# https通信のデバッグを行う方法

Tags: python, https, python-requests

（とあるurllib3パッケージを利用している、転用元コードを参考にして、）
https通信をストリームで、読み込む処理を作成しました。
利用するパッケージを統一するために、requestsパッケージで同様のことをしたく
書き換えたところ、未応答状態となり動作しませんでした。
（未応答状態となる接続先のサイトは公開できないのですが、）
https通信をデバッグするには、どのようにしていますでしょうか？

以下はurllib3を利用して、問題なく動作したコードです。
接続先https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/から、正しくレスポンスを取得できました。

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request(
    'GET',
    url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/',
    preload_content=False
)
for chunk in response.stream(1024):
    print(chunk)
```

次に、以下のようにurllib3からrequestパッケージを利用するよう書き換えました。
接続先https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/へは、
正しく動作し、レスポンスを取得できますが、他のサイト（対象の）へ接続すると未応答状態となりました。
requestsパッケージの利用方法は正しいでしょうか？
もしくはrullib3を利用したときと同じリクエストが送信されているか、確認する方法はありますでしょうか？

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/', stream=True)
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):  # Streamとして読む
    print(chunk)
```